# is it possible to overwrite MFT file table in windows api?

Tags: c, windows, system, ntfs, low-level

is it possible to overwrite MFT file table in windows api. When windows is up and ready?

I know we can read MFT but I ask about write.

Comment: You mean *just* the MFT?  Or would you include opening the block device (or whatever Windows calls it) and overwriting the whole partition?  Or finding the MFT location inside the FS and writing it that way?  (Presumably not coherent with fs caching if the filesystem is mounted.)

Comment: Find every single file mft location and write it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vista restricted raw access but you can probably still do it if you unmount the volume first.

[Changes to the file system and to the storage stack to restrict direct disk access and direct volume access in Windows Vista and in Windows Server 2008.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942448)

I don't know the type of program you are writing but it might fit in this category:

> Backup programs must unmount the volume before they write to the volume. Otherwise, the program writes will collide with file system writes. Such collisions will result in corruption or in system instability.

Writing to a live volume might be possible if you jump trough all their hoops but the risk of corruption is probably too high, you might want to investigate [obscure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/fileio/file-management-control-codes) and/or undocumented NTFS IO control codes instead.